# How to force a bridge to clone mac-address from first added physical port

Tags: network-bridge, netplan

I'm configuring KVM/QEMU on Ubuntu 18.04 using netplan.
There is corporative dhcp-server that provide a lot of mandatory data in addition to ip/netmask. 
The issue is that a bridge on setup generates its own mac-address, so it doesn't get proper ip (and other settings of course) from corporative dhcp-server. So...

How to force bridge to take/clone mac-address from first physical ports added?
Or may be there is a way to assign mac-address manually for bridge via netplan configuration?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Corresponding bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1718607

The current workaround use the *match* stanza. Bellow is an example (here with eno1 interface):

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      match:
        macaddress: <LINK_MAC_HERE>
      [..]
  bridges:
    br0:
      macaddress: <LINK_MAC_HERE>
      interfaces:
        - eno1
      [..]
```

`<LINK_MAC_HERE>` mac address can be retrieved with the following command (just after `link/ether`): `$ ip link show eno1`

After setting this, you need either to reboot, or doing the following commands:

```
$ sudo ip link set br0 down
$ sudo brctl delbr br0
$ netplan apply
```

Comment: Thanks, saved my day.