# Bridging Amazon EC2 Netplan (20.04)

Tags: netplan, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to create a bridge on my EC2 instance (Ubuntu 20.04) with netplan but I keep losing access to my machine. Currently attempting to disable ENA, but not sure if I'm simply missing something obvious. This seems similar to [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223651/bridging-amazon-ec2-with-netplan-18-04/).

My "stock" configuration is as follows:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens5:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: **:**:**:**:**:**
            set-name: ens5
    version: 2
```

with `ifconfig` and `ip a` returning:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-47:~$ ifconfig
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.45.47  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.47.255
        inet6 fe80::860:82ff:fef8:c11c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <same as macaddress>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 48418  bytes 64806497 (64.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9470  bytes 989568 (989.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 360  bytes 32234 (32.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 360  bytes 32234 (32.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-47:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:60:82:f8:c1:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.45.47/20 brd 172.31.47.255 scope global dynamic ens5
       valid_lft 3104sec preferred_lft 3104sec
    inet6 fe80::860:82ff:fef8:c11c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tried bridging just by adding `br0` and copying the macaddress over [like they did here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042241/how-to-force-a-bridge-to-clone-mac-address-from-first-added-physical-port), but wasn't able to reconnect to the EC2 instance afterwards.

I tried both

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens5:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: **:**:**:**:**:**
            set-name: ens5
    version: 2
    bridges:
        br0:
            dhcp4: true
            macaddress: **:**:**:**:**:**
            interfaces: [ens5]
```

like in netplan.io/examples for bridging and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042241/how-to-force-a-bridge-to-clone-mac-address-from-first-added-physical-port) for working around the AWS dhcp servers, and also removing the `dhcp` lines entirely, since clearly I have no idea what I'm doing.

Would really appreciate any advice, since I don't have much experience configuring networks at all. Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier to try and come up with a .yaml file for you, if: 1) you didn't redact a lot of important information, 2) you showed us what .yaml you tried that didn't work. What is *"disable ENA"*?

Comment: Apologies, I don't know enough about networking to even know what to redact. Updated the question with clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens5:
      match:
        macaddress: 0a:60:82:f8:c1:1c
      set-name: ens5
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      macaddress: 0a:60:82:f8:c1:1c
      interfaces:
        - ens5
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: This worked! Thank you!!